# convert index to column pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following pandas dataframe:

```
                    |     id    |  LocTime        |ZPos   | XPos
datetime            |               
2017-01-02 00:14:39 |20421902611|   12531245409231| 0     | -6              
2017-01-02 00:14:40 |30453291020|   28332479673070| 0     | -2
```

I want to convert datetime index to column of the data frame. 
I tried `df.reset_index(level=['datetime'])` but the result does not change.
any idea?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Need assign output back or `inplace=True` parameter:

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

---

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

---

```
print (df)
              datetime           id         LocalTime  ZPosition  XPosition
0  2017-01-02 00:14:39  10453190861  1483312478909238          0         -9
1  2017-01-02 00:14:40  10453191020  1483312479673076          0         -8
```